# How can I load an extension on sqlite3 in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, express

This my connection code :

```
`
   var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose()
   const DBSOURCE = "db_path";
   let db = new sqlite3.Database(DBSOURCE, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err.message)
        throw err
      }else{
         console.log('Connected to the SQLite database.');
      }
   });
   module.exports = db`
```

I found something here, but I dont know its the correct way to do or to make it work :
https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/Extensions#databaseloadextensionpath-callback

tried this :

```
`    let params = [];
    
    db.all(`select load_extension('./config/math.dll')`, params, (err, rows) => {
      console.log(err);
      if (err) {
        res.status(400).json({ StatusCode: 400, error: err.message });
        return;
      }
      console.log(rows)
    })`
```

and got error : Error: SQLITE_ERROR: not authorized
I couldn't find any sources for loading extension in node.js .

Answer (score 1):

Using `SELECT load_extension(...)` is disabled by default for security reasons. However, you can load an extension like this:

```
const db = new sqlite3.Database('db.sqlite3');

db.loadExtension('./lib/uuid.dll');

db.all('SELECT uuid()', (error, rows) => {
  console.log(rows);
});

db.close();
```

Notice the file name `uuid.dll` is not accidental. In my case, the [uuid extension](https://sqlite.org/src/file/ext/misc/uuid.c) contains entry-point function called `sqlite3_uuid_init`, therefore the file must be called `uuid.<extension>` to make it work out of box. You can read more in [SQLite documentation](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/load_extension.html).